# Thread in Service Android

Tags: android, multithreading

For my App. I am using the Background service i.e, Lifecycle that excutes for every 200 ms . Now i want the Thread in Service which checks some condition if the lifecycle is on. Can anyone please suggest me how can i implement this logic.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a Thread in the `Service` class with come kind of callback. Services are not some magical, remote components of the app, you can create Threads in them just fine. Or even better, go for an `AsyncTask` instead of Thread, as it has a callback mechanism already implemented (the onProgressUpdate() method) :-)